# Script injected with insertAdjacentHTML() does not execute

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In my app, I send a request from the client to a node.js server.  The server sends an HTML response containing a script:

```js
app.post('/verify', cors(issue2options), async (req, res) => {
    let auth = await mongo({
        input: 'express app',
        data: req.body['auth']['address'],
        type: 'verify'
    }, 'get', 'type')

    if (empty(auth)) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(`
            <div id="registration" slot="varan-about">
                Войдите под аккаунтом администратора
                <script type="module">
                    console.log('sssss');
                </script>
            </div>
        `));
    } else {
        res.send(true)
    }
})
```

On the client I inject the response into `document.body` using `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', json);
```

But the script does not execute.

Is it possible to inject a script using this method?

Comment: It is really difficult to tel from your code.. Since you're receiving data, my first guess is that you're calling insertAdjacentHTML before the information exists to be appended.

Comment: Then string get to client document['body'] is empty and i insert this[`<div></div> <script> console.log()</script>`]  string. I m dot't use createElement('script'), but i dot know there tag <script> in string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [official HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0):

> script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are
>   inserted.

Inserting the adjacent HTML is the same as modifying `innerHTML` of a specific DOM element.

If you really want to provide a mixture of html, css and javascript back from your server, you might want to put each part into a respective property.
For example: `{"js": "<Some js here">, "html": "<Some markup here>", "css": "<Some styles here>"}`
Then, on the client side, you can create a script tag and inline your logic to it:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = data.js;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

The style could be handled in the similar fashion:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = data.css;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Finally, the markup could be changed via `innerHTML` but keep in mind that this will not remove any event handlers attached to the DOM elements that will have been replaced by new elements after parsing new HTML:

```
var someNode = document.querySelector('<some selector>');
someNode.innerHTML = data.html;
```

Answer (score 7):

As many of the answers have pointed out, attempting to insert the script directly as text will prevent it from running. Here is one method that works:

```
const divFragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`${json}`);
document.body.prepend(divFragment);
```

Sources:

- https://grrr.tech/posts/create-dom-node-from-html-string/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can user `insertAdjacentHTML` with any 
for more infformation visit this page 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

in you implementation, I think you don't have to create DOM on server side, just get the response and create DOM on client side in JS

like

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.text = 'My new Paragraph :)'

function myFunction() {
  var h = document.getElementById("myH2");
  h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", p.text);
}
```

```html
<h2 id="myH2">My Header</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Insert a paragraph</button>
```

Comment: You missed the fact that the script won't work if you insert it to the DOM using insertAdjacentHTML. That was the initial author's concern. The HTML5 spec clearly says: "script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.". insertAdjacentHTML is not way different that innerHTML.