# Can't execute inline script with Element.insertAdjacentHTML()

Tags: javascript

Can I use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to execute inline javascript?

What works in the browser console:

```
$('body').append('<script>alert(1)</script>')
```

What I need to work in browser console:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<script>alert(1)</script>');
```

The VanillaJS solution does not work. I would be glad about a reason

Comment: [Can I use Element.insertAdjacentHTML() to insert tag script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209520/can-i-use-element-insertadjacenthtml-to-insert-tag-script/57211515#57211515)

Comment: i think because you didnt specify any element

Answer (score 1):

Using `insertAdjacentHTML`, although the script tag is added to the page, it won't be parsed or executed.

For the script to actually run you need to use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerText = "console.log('Hello!');";

document.body.append(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var script = document.createElement('script'); // create a new script element 

script.innerText = "alert('Hello!');"; // InnerText property html-encodes the content, 
document.body.append(script); //append innterText to script
```