# Javascript adding custom meta tags, css and/or scripts to the head or before the </body> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react/redux page that makes a call to an API that in the response that can return things that will need to be added to either before the `</head>`(head) or before the `</body>` (footer). They can be custom meta tags, css and/or scripts. I tried doing `window.document.head.appendChild` but that only works on nodes and I have to create the element.

The response should come back in the correct format so for example

```
<meta name=test123> <script type=text/javascript src=test123></script>
```

I tried doing `window.document.head.innerHTML = <script ...>` which appends it to the top but then it messes up all of the styling for some reason.
When I did `window.document.head.innerHTML += <script ...>` it caused lots of repeats.

So I was wondering what's the best way to do this because from the googling I've done I've only seen the `appendChild` mentioned most of the time.

Also what would the best way to append it to before the `</body>`(footer) tag?

Comment: Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69155001) to insert it `beforeend` of the `<head>`

Comment: The HTML5 spec clearly says: "script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.". insertAdjacentHTML is not way different that innerHTML. I don't think this will work

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72639251) looks like a great approach. There's also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: Thanks will take a look into those!